# Multiple DataNavigateUrlFields... one from datasource, one from drpdownlist

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

Lets say I have a drop down list and a grid view on a page like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCategories" runat="server" >
<Columns>
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="CategoryName"            DataNavigateUrlFields="CategoryID"     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Learning.aspx?categoryID={0" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I'd like to add this to the URL:
&view=<%=SelectedDropdownlistvalue%>

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use TemplateField as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCategories" runat="server" >
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CategoryName", "~/Learning.aspx?categoryID={0}")+" &view=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue %>' 
                        Text="Goto Page"></asp:HyperLink>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Remember the DropDownList.SelectedValue is obtained at postBack, so the link is constructed at that time. To change the link dynamically when the value of the dropdownlist changes set the AutoPostBack="true" of the dropdownlist.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the response. I did experiment with the templateField, but have not been able to get the syntax correct for retrievieng the selected value from the dropdownlist . I have tried a bunch... any chance you could give a sample?

Comment: I've tested the above code and its fine. Can I see the dropdownlist's markup and be sure that CategoryName is not null. Is the gridView is getting data? Make sure that you have AutoPostBack set to true.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I ended up resolving what I needed by adjusting the Hyperlink as follows:  <asp:GridView ID="gvCategories" runat="server" > <Columns> <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="CategoryName"            DataNavigateUrlFields="CategoryID"     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Learning.aspx?categoryID={0" /> </Columns> </asp:GridView>

Comment: Disregard thr previous comment. Thanks for all the feedback. I ended up resolving what I needed by adjusting the Hyperlink in the item template as follows: ' NavigateURL='<%=String.Format("somepage.aspx?category={0}&View={2}", Eval("CategoryName"), DropDownList1.SelectedValue %>' '